# Google Compute Engine Automated Load Test VM Instance?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, load-testing, locust

I have a simple web server application in a docker container that I have pinned to a vm instance in GCP Compute Engine.

I am wondering how to set up automated load testing (Locust load testing via GKE) on the web server application running on my VM instance?

I saw a tutorial here: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/distributed-load-testing-using-gke. But this involves using App Engine. I am not able to find a GCP tutorial to auto load test vm instances in Compute Engine.

Any links or ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial comprises of a project that you clone from github. from that project you deploy a  `sample-webapp` to Google Compute Engine, with a domain such as *test1.appspot.com*.
This *test1.appspot.com* is the target for the **Locust** cluster.

This `sample-webapp` is a simple Flask app that you can copy and deploy in your instance in GCP (there are several ways of accomplishing this). Once the app is deployed and reachable from the internet, you need supply its address/domain as the target for the **Locust** cluster.